# Como puedo saber cuando se va a una url predeterminada

Tags: php, html

Buenas noches tengo un programa que genere un boton para pagar.
Pero necesito saber cuando se cancela el pago.
y cuando se hace.

Ahora estoy probando y coloque que cuando cancele se dirija a google..
pero quiero saber como tomo una variable que me confirme cuando cancelo y otra cuando pago.

Ser miembro activo

Es que son tipo "hidden" y no los entiendo bien... 
Quiero saber que cuando se de click aquí

haya una forma de saberlo.

y cuando de aquí

```
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_url" value="https://www.facebook.com/">
```

también haya una forma de saberlo mediante PHP.

Espero me ayuden por favor.

Answer (score 0):

no has pensando en tomar el `name` como variable desde javascript?

podrias hacer algo asi:

```
var name=document.getElementById("d").name;
```

y podrias hacer algo asi:

```js
    document.onclick = function(event) {
        event = event || window.event; // IE specials
 var name=document.getElementById("pagar").name;
        if(name=== "pagar") {
            alert('fue un pago');
        } else{
        
          alert("cancelacion");
        }
    };
```

[fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833110/get-the-input-box-name-using-javascript)

Explico mi codigo:

> primero creo una funcion para esuchcar un **onclick** despues obtengo
> el ID o Name del elemento (eso ya es tu decision) despues veo si el
> elemento seleccionado es pagar si es pagar manda un mensaje de que es
> pagar y si no es ps manda otro mensaje diciendo que no es pago.

ese codigo lo cree leendo tu pregunta espero que te sirva.

*pst no lo testier*

Comment: Gracias.. pero es que mira.. Entras al perfil del cliente cierto.. 
le das click en un  boton que dice ser miembro activo.. despues te carga una pagina para pagar...

te salen dos botones cancelar pago ó procesar pago..

Cuando le das cancelar .. te lleva a una dirección ..
si le das procesar te lleva a otra dirección

Y no se como darme cuenta si lo pago o lo cancelo

Comment: La verdad no me funciona esa parte